# What is non-final variable?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am not understanding the concept of `final` variable. In a `for` loop I have dynamic variable `i` which is crucial for me to refer an array. As soon as I use `i`, it throws me an error saying it should be `final`.

What exactly is `final`? Could you please help to get rid of that error?

My code is here:

```
for( int i = 0; i <4; i++)
{

   Bitmap celeb1=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(fimagearray[i]);
   Bitmap celeb1_focus=Bitmap.getBitmapResource(fimagearray[i]);
   ImageButton celebbutton = new ImageButton(celeb1, celeb1_focus);

   celebbutton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

       public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
       {
           UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new FetchTweets(fusernamearray[i]));

       }
   });


   femaleSec.add(celebbutton);
}
```

Comment: Can't tell from your code - would be useful if you could post a stacktrace - but usually you need to declare local variables as `final` if you want to pass them to a new thread, which one of the methods you're calling may do. Try creating a `final` version of `i` and using that: `final int j = i;`.

Comment: `final`, by the way, means that the value of the variable cannot be reassigned. If the variable is immutable, (like primitives or `String`s), this means it can't be changed. If it's a mutable object, the variable cannot be changed to refer to a different object, but the internals of the object can still be changed.

Comment: @Russell: *"Can't tell from your code"* [sic]  <--  But three people could tell from its code ; )

Comment: Then I guess I didn't pay enough attention! :-)

Comment: I would prefer to have one FieldChangeListener for all these cells and in fieldChanged calculate index from cell field index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An anonymous inner class can only access `final` variables from the outer scope. Since `i` is not final, it can't be accessed directly. You can't make `i` final since it needs to change, and a final variable can't be changed.

As a simple workaround, copy the value of `i` into a final variable during each loop iteration:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    final int index = i; // <-- copy i to `index' to use in FieldChangeListener

    // ...

    celebbutton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
               new FetchTweets(fusernamearray[index])); // <-- `index'
        }
    });


    femaleSec.add(celebbutton);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me understand about final variable, before I tried declaring "index" variable as final before the for loop, that's why everytime the "index" value used to be 0 ... Now, the problem is solved, as in your code, you are declaring "i" as final everytime it enters the loop...Thanks a lot for making me understand!!! :) This solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement

Check out the [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) link for it.

Also Look at [this](http://www.java-examples.com/java-final-variable-example) Example.

Comment: Thanks for the links... it was useful

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use the value of `i` inside of an 'Anonymous Inner Class' which requires that all non-local variables to that class be declared as `final`, meaning that the variable's value may not be changed once it has been initialized.

The solution posted by @aix would solve your problem.